# How to collect cell values in excel and make them into one column

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I'm brand new to coding and to this forum, so please accept my apologies in advance for being a newbie and probably not understanding what i'm supposed to say!

I was asked a question which I didn't know how to approach earlier. The user was trying to collect cell values in multiple rows from Excel (split out by a delimiter) and then create one complete column of single values in rows. Example in picture1 below. Source file is how the data is received and output is what the user is trying to do with it:

[image: Picture1]

I hope I have explained that correctly. I'm looking for some python code that will automate it. There could be thousands of values that need putting into rows

Thanks in advance!

Andy

Comment: Hi Andy, can you tell us what you already tried? Which libraries do you want to use?

If its just about getting data from one excel row and printing it in another range of rows, why do the detour with Python? You can just use VBA for that.

That said, if you feel more comfortable with Python (I dont blame you, VBA is my nightmare too), I would recommend using xlrd: http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the openpyxl package:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

This allows you to directly access cells in your excel sheet within python.
As some of your cells seem to contain multiple values separated by semicolons you could read the cells as strings and use the

```
splitstring = somelongstring.split(';')
```

to seperate the values. This results in a list containing the separated values

Basic manipulations using this package are described in this tutorial:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

Edit:
An example iterating over all columns in a worksheet would be:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')

for row in wb.iter_cols(values_only=True):
    for value in row:
       do_something(value)
```

Comment: Thanks @oliverm i'll check it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find some code online and butcher is to get what I needed. Here is the code I ended up with:

```
import pandas as pd

iris = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
from itertools import chain

# return list from series of comma-separated    strings
def chainer(s):
    return       list(chain.from_iterable(s.str.split(',')))

# calculate lengths of splits
lens = iris['Order No'].str.split(',').map(len)

# create new dataframe, repeating or chaining as appropriate
res = pd.DataFrame({'Order No':   np.repeat(iris['Order No'], lens),'Order No':   chainer(iris['Order No'])})
```